# Hyperledger Fabric warning after adding new org to channel

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperldger-fabric-peer

after the synchronization block is complete, when commit block, log show warnning like:

```
[33m2021-09-30 14:55:04.306 CST [gossip.gossip] validateMsg -> WARN 48e0e[0m StateInfo message GossipMessage: Channel: , nonce: 0, tag: CHAN_OR_ORG state_info_message: Timestamp:inc_num:1632823876288936547 seq_num:1632984903634814456 PKI-id:ed091bb9d5e18cb267ab1da04a3110acd4be03881ce2a8ae69315e0797d48b4b channel MAC:7cd510f4d93d80a10bb6c19005e6d9179ec805d5555f70ad6cfa626a221c4137 properties:ledger_height:65586 chaincodes:<name:"datacatalog" version:"3" > chaincodes:<name:"_lifecycle" version:"1" > , Envelope: 136 bytes, Signature: 71 bytes is found invalid: PKIID wasn't found
```

but the network looks normal, submit transaction also normal.

Comment: Check out this https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-6092. It could give you some hints.

Comment: It did not tell me how to fix it, the difference is that: i can instantiate chaincode successfully

Comment: Hi. Did you solve the problem then? In my case somehow the chaincode is installed and committed but doesn't appear as a container for the node which shows these warning.